# running .net code written in vs 2005 in vs 2010

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have a solution written in asp.net VS 2005 and I want to open it in VS 2010. When i open it through VS 2010, it does a project conversion and later it shows a folder with no files..ie project file was unloaded...Can anyone help me resolve this?

Comment: http://vishaljoshi.blogspot.com/2009/05/vs-2010-project-conversion-upgrade.html

Comment: Do you get any errors from the conversion process?

Comment: I dont see any file in the solution..i just see instead of files..the project file was unloaded

Comment: And what happens when you try to load the project file?

Comment: Tim..i dont get any Project Upgrade dialog when i do conversion..i am not able to upload screen shot...when i try to load the project build in VS 2010 it just give me empty solution..i dont receive any error too

Comment: in conversion logs it says Solution converted successfully....but i cant see any file in the solution

Comment: when i open again in 2010 i am getting error that file cannot be opened because its project type (.dtproj) is not suppoerted by this version of application.

Comment: @deepak: If you want to notify somebody don't write f.e. _Tim_ but `@Tim` (note the _at sign_). http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work

Answer (score 1):

SSIS/SSAS is not supported in VS 2010   as opposed to VS 2005.

Have a look here:

http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/508552/ssis-vs2010-project-type